# cURL not saving the image correctly

Tags: php, curl

```
$ch = curl_init();
$fp = fopen("$localName",'w');

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $src);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER,1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 5.01; Windows NT 5.0)");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 200);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, "http://google.com");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION, CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
$rawdata=curl_exec ($ch);
curl_close ($ch);

fwrite($fp, $rawdata); 
fclose($fp);
```

... writes the file but invalid (0 bytes). Please tell me what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turned out the problem was some images were loaded but with 302 redirect status message which confused the curl.

Answer (score 1):

I ran your code and there were some errors. I have rectified those here:

```
$src = '<URL to the image>';
$ch = curl_init($src);

//curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp); This option is not required
//curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $host); Since you are setting the source in init skip this
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER,1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 5.01; Windows NT 5.0)");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 200);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, "http://google.com");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION, CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE); // Follows redirect responses.

$raw=curl_exec($ch);
if ($raw === false) {
    trigger_error(curl_error($ch));
}

curl_close ($ch);
$localName = basename($src); // The file name of the source can be used locally       
if(file_exists($localName)){    
    unlink($localName);
}

$fp = fopen($localName,'wb');
fwrite($fp, $raw);
fclose($fp);
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked somewhat. Now a few images are grabbed correctly but most still fail (0bytes),could it be a timeout issue?

Comment: @Nimbuz 200 seconds for timeout should be more than adequate. Are you sure the failing URLS are reachable?

Comment: @Nimbuz I have added error checking on the result. Try running the modified version of the script and you should see the reason for failure.

Comment: AHA. I think I found it. most of the images return status `302` and some return `200`. If I enter the url in browser they all load, but I think cURL doesn't return anything other than 200 'OK' status? Those that return 302 are not copied correctly.

Comment: @Nimbuz I have added the "FOLLOWLOCATION" to follow redirect responses. Now it should work for all your URLS.

Comment: Nope, 0 byte files still. :(

Comment: 0 is either a header redirect or some error. See response code for the one other than 200. You can see if it's error via `curl_error($ch)` and `curl_errno($ch)`.

Answer (score 0):

Try add a header() for image type.

For example, if it is a PNG image, add in your code:

```
// ...
header('Content-type: image/png');
file_put_contents($raw);
```

Comment: but I'm not sure if it would a JPEG or PNG

Answer (score 0):

Had a play, all you seem to need is the following:

```
<?
$src = 'http://bit.ly/TT5N5M';

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $src);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
$output = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

$fp = fopen("img.jpg",'w');
fwrite($fp, $output);
fclose($fp);
```

Comment: Its a direct link to the remote image, I verified that its publicly accessible. `http://domain.net/zen/sites/default/files/styles/new-popup/public/photos/new/category1/2012-11/18136/18-11-2012-252054-img1873.jpg` (example)

Comment: That means nothing without context... what are you showing me?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/19748/discussion-between-duellsy-and-nimbuz)

Comment: I've updated my solution to include the ability to follow redirection, which should help with the 302's